# jquery clone login bar on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

based in this ex. http://jsfiddle.net/fj8wM/181/ if I click on login link when is not scolled it work but if U scroll it doesnt work. 
I'm trying to make a login bar when I click on login link to take me on top of the page and show me the login form.
In this case it go on top top but not show the alert. Anyone have idea how to go on top and show the alert at same time???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to a `live()`-click-handler and add a `return false;`. Also see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LqaWk/

```
$('#login').live('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
    return false;
});
```